# Unable to Display Summary Band in report generated in Excel

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, dynamic-jasper

I have created a report using ireports and add the text fields in Summary band to display the Average values .

I am able to get those in pdf , csv formats but unable to display summary band fields in Excel.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please paste your report xml here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an answer by now, but I've seen this happening if the fields dimensions overlap. Check the settings for each field. In iReport/Jasper Studio, go to Properties and check width (w) and height (h) values 
and make sure they align properly (no overlap).